# Best way of outputting a spreadsheet format with bold markup from python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I currently output data from python in csv format (which I both read back in to python, and also view in excel).

I am looking to make certain words in the outputted text bold, for when I view in excel (basically so I can quickly visibly determine where in a block a text certain words are occurring).

What is the best way of outputting spreadsheets with minimal formatting? I know cvs is supposed to be formating free. I thought about enclosing the desired bold words with the html < b >word<\b> format, but wasn't sure if/how I could then get excel to interpret this correctly.

Ideally looking for something which opens correctly in excel, but can also be read back I to python in a similar by-row manner that csv files are.

(nb - I can code up inserting e.g. < b > tags where I desire them fine - it is knowing what tags to put, how to save the file, and how to get excel to interpret these tags that I don't know)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749020/how-to-bold-csv-data-in-excel

Comment: Short answer is that you can't do this in CSV, which is a data-only format.

Comment: Is there a another cvs/txt-esque format which does allow encoding formatting tags within simple text?

Answer (score 0):

for reference, since I am only using internally, I ended up putting in   tags into the CSV output, and then using VBA within excel to the convert to the desired format, using the answer to this question - [VBA code in excel to made text between tags bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597177/vba-code-in-excel-to-made-text-between-tags-bold)