# VBA code in excel to made text between tags bold

Tags: vba, excel

I have a csv file which includes the html tags < b > and <\ b > to signify bold text. (I.e several words between these tags, in a longer block of text within the cell, should be bold). Is there a way using vba code in excel to strip the tags, and make the text between the tags bold?

Note - There are sometime multiple sets of tags within a given cell.

Comment: Are the html tags always inside a set of commas - i.e. `one,<b>two<\b>, three`, or do they ever span them - i.e. `one,<b>two, three<\b>`?

Comment: The tags do not span over the commas, but not all text between the commas is in the tags e.g. A three cell example may be: one,not bold < b > bold < \b > not bold < b> bold again <\b> not,three

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Sub BoldTags()
Dim X As Long, BoldOn As Boolean
BoldOn = False 'Default from start of cell is not to bold
For X = 1 To Len(ActiveCell.Text)
    If UCase(Mid(ActiveCell.Text, X, 3)) = "<B>" Then
        BoldOn = True
        ActiveCell.Characters(X, 3).Delete
    End If
    If UCase(Mid(ActiveCell.Text, X, 4)) = "</B>" Then
        BoldOn = False
        ActiveCell.Characters(X, 4).Delete
    End If
    ActiveCell.Characters(X, 1).Font.Bold = BoldOn
Next
End Sub
```

Currently set to run on the activecell, you can just plop it in a loop to do a whole column. You can easily adapt this code for other HTML tags for Cell formatting (ie italic etc)

This was in the cell I tested on (minus the space after <): Sample < b>Te< /b>st of < B>bolding< /B> end

The result was: Sample **Te**st of **bolding** end

Hope that helps