# Modyfing a VBA code to select the entire column insteed just one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I found this in this site, write it by Dan Donoghue

```
Sub BoldTags()
Dim X As Long, BoldOn As Boolean

BoldOn = False 'Default from start of cell is not to bold

For X = 1 To Len(ActiveCell.Text)
    If UCase(Mid(ActiveCell.Text, X, 3)) = "<B>" Then
        BoldOn = True
        ActiveCell.Characters(X, 3).Delete
    End If
    If UCase(Mid(ActiveCell.Text, X, 4)) = "</B>" Then



    BoldOn = False
        ActiveCell.Characters(X, 4).Delete
    End If
    ActiveCell.Characters(X, 1).Font.Bold = BoldOn
Next
End Sub
```

I don't know anything about coding or magic or this.

Comment: What do you want it to do instead of what it's doing now?

Comment: "I don't know nothing" is particularly torturous to la langue Anglais but, more importantly, reminds me of the uncouth youngster I was many decades ago when I spoked like that. Changed to "anything" :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597177/vba-code-in-excel-to-made-text-between-tags-bold?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over the cells in the activecell's column:

```
Sub BoldTags(r As Range)
    Dim X As Long, BoldOn As Boolean

    BoldOn = False 'Default from start of cell is not to bold

    For X = 1 To Len(r.Text)
        If UCase(Mid(r.Text, X, 3)) = "<B>" Then
            BoldOn = True
            r.Characters(X, 3).Delete
        End If
        If UCase(Mid(r.Text, X, 4)) = "</B>" Then
            BoldOn = False
            r.Characters(X, 4).Delete
        End If
        r.Characters(X, 1).Font.Bold = BoldOn
    Next
End Sub


Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    For Each r In rng
        Call BoldTags(r)
    Next r
End Sub
```

NOTE:

The `Call` is not really necessary
Make sure the list does not contain empties.

Comment: It works! thanks a lot

PS. Me comere unos tacos en tu honor.

Comment: @Atlahuatl de nada

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
Sub BoldTags()
Dim rng As Range, X As Long, BoldOn As Boolean
' This works on a selection of cells, if you want it on a full column comment out the next line and uncomment the one below.
For Each rng In Selection
'For Each rng In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    BoldOn = False 'Default from start of cell is not to bold
    For X = 1 To Len(rng.Text)
        If UCase(Mid(rng.Text, X, 3)) = "<B>" Then
            BoldOn = True
            rng.Characters(X, 3).Delete
        End If
        If UCase(Mid(rng.Text, X, 4)) = "</B>" Then
            BoldOn = False
            rng.Characters(X, 4).Delete
        End If
        rng.Characters(X, 1).Font.Bold = BoldOn
    Next
Next
End Sub
```