# Print CSV headers in bold text in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, export-to-csv

My CSV is getting generated totally correct. I want to print the CSV headers bold. Is there any way to print them in bold.

My code that prints the simple CSV.

```
<%= CSV.generate do |csv|

    csv << ["REF", "Customer Name", "Property Address", "Moving Date", "Mobile Phone", "Operator", "Status"]
    @results.each do |result|
        csv << [result.id, result.customer_name, result.address_label, result.moving_date.strftime("%b %d, %Y"), "", result.operator.try(:name), result.status ]

end.html_safe
%>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you try wrapping their values with `<strong>VALUE</strong>`? e.g instead of `"REF"` it would become `"<strong>REF</strong>"`.

Comment: @TamerShlash That would be parsed weirdly or would get parsed but in plaintext.

I'm fairly certain this can't be done. CSV doesn't support formatting (aside of course from printing it as caps) -- it's just plain data. If you want to do formatting, CSV is not the file type for you. And oh, here -- this explains better your situation.

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749020/how-to-bold-csv-data-in-excel)

Comment: I was thinking about your question and many people confuse CSV with XLS, because excel open most csv files, CSV do not have any formats what you really want to do is export a XLS

Answer (score 2):

this can't be done; CSV is a text plain format.

So you will need another file type document to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I used a gem called '[axlsx_rails](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails)' to help out and its really simple

example of my controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order('created_at DESC')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xlsx {
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="all_products.xlsx"'
      }
    end
  end
end
```

example of my xlsx view

```
#app/views/products/index.xlsx.axlsx
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.styles do |style|
  header_cell = style.add_style(b: true)

  wb.add_worksheet(name: "Products") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ["Title", "Price"], :style=>[header_cell, header_cell]
    @products.each do |product|
     sheet.add_row [product.title, product.price]
    end
  end
end
```

link to that view

```
<%= link_to 'Download as .xlsx', products_path(format: :xlsx) %>
```

if you want to see the sample code in action I created a git repo where you can see all I did https://github.com/mzaragoza/sample_exporting_xls

Hope that this helps